# Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered while importing data

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to import some data and getting the error

> "Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered"

the file I'm trying to import is at
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/snksales/dimdistributor.csv

not able to understand how to fix this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This file appears to be encoded as UTF-16. BigQuery only supports UTF-8 and latin1 text encodings. Can you reformat it as UTF-8 or ascii? If you are using windows, you should be able to set the encoding by doing a save-as in notepad. If you are using linux or mac, you should be able to do: `iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8  dimdistributor.csv -o dimdistributor_utf8.csv`. I ran the latter and was able to import your data.

$xxd dimdistributor.csv | head
0000000: fffe 3100 2c00 3000 3000 3000 3000 3100  ..1.,.0.0.0.0.1.
0000010: 3000 3000 3000 3000 3200 2c00 4d00 2e00  0.0.0.0.2.,.M...
0000020: 4d00 2e00 4500 4e00 5400 4500 5200 5000  M...E.N.T.E.R.P.
0000030: 5200 4900 5300 4500 5300 2c00 3200 0d00  R.I.S.E.S.,.2...
0000040: 0a00 3200 2c00 3000 3000 3000 3000 3100  ..2.,.0.0.0.0.1.

Comment: thanks jordan,.i  was able to do the conversion and this worked.

Comment: another question... i am actually downloading this data from sqlserver, and i have another file which is 20gb in size. that wont open in notepad. is there a way i can get data from sql server in utf-8 format (it doesnt really seem to support utf-8) ,, or is there another utility to convert on windows.?

Comment: I don't know of another tool to convert to utf8 on windows, but you should be able to install cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/) and run iconv as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Try cleaning the file with the following PowerShell script:

```
   $configFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\InputPath\* 
   foreach ($file in $configFiles)
   {
         (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
         Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "`0", "" } |
         Set-Content $file.PSPath
   }
```

For using it, just copy your file in C:\InputPath, save the script as Script.ps1 and run it with PowerShell

Comment: I tried this on a file BCP-ed from SQL server using 65001 code page and was able to import the file to bigQuery

Answer (score 1):

I tried powershell script but it was fast only for ~1 GB file size. For the 16GB file I had it just took forever and actually never finished.

I also had BOM characters in my UTF-8 format csv file I generated via BCP from SQL server.

So this is what I did for a very large csv file. Used [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) utility to compress in gzip format followed by uploading to GCP cloud storage where I used gsutil command to unzip and remove any ascii 0 characters and save the file again.

```
gsutil cp gs://csvfiles/originalbaddatafile.csv.gz - | gunzip | tr -d '\000' | gsutil cp - gs://csvfiles/goodfile.csv
```